# How to use expose-loader with Jest

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

When I run Jest tests I get an error when it parses a file that contains an import with `expose-loader`:

*index.js:*

```
import 'expose-loader?PIXI!phaser-ce/build/custom/pixi';
```

And the error is:

```
Cannot find module 'expose-loader?PIXI!phaser-ce/build/custom/pixi' from 'index.js'
```

Comment: shouldn't you use `require`? (`Note: Modules must be require()'d within in your bundle, or they will not be exposed.`)

Comment: @Edwin I don't think it matters, it should work both ways, I don't have any problems using import on the build. The error occurs only when executing the tests with Jest.

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?